# C# WPF UserControl based on Uniformgrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uniformgrid

I'm trying to make the user control on the basis of UniformGrid. When using office error appears: **The property 'Content' is set more than once**

AdaptiveLayout.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="App.Controls.AdaptiveLayout"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:element="clr-namespace:App.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UniformGrid SizeChanged="UniformGrid_SizeChanged">
        <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
    </UniformGrid>

</UserControl>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
...
<controls:AdaptiveLayout TransferringAfter="190">
         <controls:TextBoxWrapControl LabelContent="FirstName"></controls:TextBoxWrapControl>
         <controls:TextBoxWrapControl LabelContent="LastName"></controls:TextBoxWrapControl>
 </controls:AdaptiveLayout>
...
```

Comment: When you want to "make the user control on the basis of UniformGrid" and want to add child elements to it, you should explain why you can't directly use a UniformGrid (instead of your control). What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To elements are floating, and at the same time stretched when you change the content width. https://s3.postimg.org/wc2dqkayb/323.png

Comment: You should probably create a [custom panel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx#Panels_custom_panel_elements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *using* a `UniformGrid` in your UserControl, but that does not actually *make* it into one. That's why it's complaining in your MainWindow.xaml that you set more than one content for your `AdaptiveLayout`.
You could try extending `UniformGrid` instead of using it.

Comment: It's no witchcraft. Just make a new class that extends `UniformGrid` like you'd do with any other class that uses inheritance. In the constructor can you then register your own event handler for the SizeChanged event, since that seems to be all you're after.